# How to query keys that have all the values from another table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table called table1 that has two columns, key and value. I have another table called Values that has some values in it.
How can I query to get keys that have all the corresponding values that are in the Values table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
select key
     , count(*)
from 
     (select distinct
             Table1.key
           , Table1.value
      from   Table1
       inner join Values
          on Values.value = Table1.value
     )
group by key
having count(*) = (select count(distinct value) from Values)
```

The having clause allows filtering on aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest method:

```
select t1.key
from table1 t1 join
     Values v
     on v.value = t1.value
group by t1.key
having count(distinct value) = (select count(*) from values);
```

Note:  This assumes that `values` has no duplicates.

Obviously `values` and `key` are really bad names for identifiers, because they are SQL keywords.  Hopefully your actually names don't have such conflicts.